# Android Error When Calling "requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS );" in Activity

Tags: android

I'm attempting to display loading progress for a WebView in an Android Activity. When I attempt to display the window's progress bar with:

```
requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS );
```

as per http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#progressbar but at this point I get a debugging error.

When the error occurs I see a new tab "ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity" in Eclipse which has a message "Source not found." and a button "Edit Source Lookup Path...".

When I remove the offending line I don't get this error.

What could be causing this problem? Do I need to set a permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: can you post the error message and the method that contains your requestWindowFeature call?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried making your `requestWindowFeature()` call before you call `setContentView()`?

This is necessary according to [this post](http://osdir.com/ml/Android-Beginners/2009-11/msg00008.html).

The docs for [Window.requestFeature():](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#requestFeature(int))

> Enable extended screen features. This
>   must be called before
>   setContentView(). May be called as
>   many times as desired as long as it is
>   before setContentView().

Comment: Gold, that did the trick. I'm still not seeing a progress bar in the emulator but at least it isn't breaking any more... Cheers, Zac

Comment: You may have to actually set the progress as well

Comment: I'm calling before setContentView() and is still crashing, any idea about my the problem? :(

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

instead of:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are calling `requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS );` before you call `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - doing this as per yours and Mathew Willis' answers fixed the problem. Cheers, Zac

Answer (score 0):

It was changing to targetSdkVersion to 19 that made mine not work. And it was specifically the function requestWindowFeature function that broke it all. I removed it from my Manifest xml and just used minSdkVersion to 8 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

aliosmeen is right. You need extend `Activity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`. Both classes for some reason implement the `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);` method differently. I did it this way and it does not crash anymore. Although, you must call the `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);` method  before you call the `setContentView()` method.